# JHipster translation not found

Tags: jhipster

I created a brandnew jhipster project. In it I also created some entity components which I would like to reuse as nested component. When I create a new module and inside a new component and try to use the entity as nested component, the translation is not working:

[image]

I am using the entity component in the new module/component as follows (jhi-pet is the selector of the entity component):

```
<mat-card>
<h1>Main Content....</h1>

<jhi-pet></jhi-pet>
```

As seen in the picture the entity list gets displayed in the new component but translation does not work.

Another option would be link to the entity as a route (as follows)

```
{
  path: 'pet', component: PetComponent
}
```

Same issue here. The entity list gets displayed but no translation.

If I go directly to the entity page like /pets then translation works...

Here is my jhipster configuration:

```
    "generator-jhipster": {
"promptValues": {
  "packageName": "com.rem.app",
  "nativeLanguage": "tr"
},
"jhipsterVersion": "5.2.1",
"applicationType": "monolith",
"baseName": "REM",
"packageName": "com.rem.app",
"packageFolder": "com/rem/app",
"serverPort": "8080",
"authenticationType": "jwt",
"cacheProvider": "ehcache",
"enableHibernateCache": true,
"websocket": false,
"databaseType": "sql",
"devDatabaseType": "h2Disk",
"prodDatabaseType": "postgresql",
"searchEngine": "elasticsearch",
"messageBroker": false,
"serviceDiscoveryType": false,
"buildTool": "maven",
"enableSwaggerCodegen": false,
"jwtSecretKey": "replaced-by-jhipster-info",
"clientFramework": "angularX",
"useSass": true,
"clientPackageManager": "yarn",
"testFrameworks": [],
"jhiPrefix": "jhi",
"enableTranslation": true,
"nativeLanguage": "tr",
"languages": [
  "tr",
  "en",
  "de"
```

Any idea how I can use the proper translation?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 4):

Found the answert!

In the new module which uses the entity as nested component add this to the constructor

```
constructor(private languageService: JhiLanguageService, private languageHelper: JhiLanguageHelper) {
 this.languageHelper.language.subscribe((languageKey: string) => {
  if (languageKey !== undefined) {
    this.languageService.changeLanguage(languageKey);
  }
 });
}
```

Comment: correct answer.. this has to be loaded per module I guess, what if this can be loaded in the main module and then can be used everywhere? did you try that?